# RDLC Reports: how to hide text, depending on whether all fields in dataset value are NULL?

Tags: textbox, report, expression, rdlc

I am creating RDLC Reports (this one is a subreport actually), that hides a specific Text-Box depending on data available/missing.

Specifically, I want to hide a Text Box, using an "Expression", when all values of a specific DataSet are null. Currently I do only check the first value like so:

```
=(IsNothing(First(Fields!EventDescription.Value, "MyDataSet")))
```

This works, regarding only the first item in the DataSet, or when it's empty. **How can I check for "All". Is there an "All" operator?**

Answer (score 0):

I now have

```
=((Sum(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!EventDescription.Value),0,1), "MyDataSet") ) = 0)
```

which looks a little complicated, but works. It

- checks whether the given Field is NULL
- if not so, provides the integer value 1
- sums all those values up
- hides the text box, when the sum is zero (all fields have been null)

Essentially this converts an aggregate comparison into a sum.